# Cannot justify NavItems in React-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <MenuBar />
        <Container fluid={true}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/task" component={Task} />
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
}


function MenuBar() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" fixed="bottom">
      <LinkContainer exact to="/">
        <Navbar.Brand>App</Navbar.Brand>
      </LinkContainer>

      <Nav className="mr-auto" variant="tabs" justify="true">
        <Nav.Item>
          <LinkContainer exact to="/">
            <Nav.Link active={false}>Home</Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <LinkContainer exact to="/task">
            <Nav.Link active={false}>Task</Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Why the navItems don't fill evenly? I want the tabs to fill the whole width of screen.I have tried to change the Nav.Link to Nav.Item,it still dosen't work. What should I do? please help me.

I removed the navbar and it works, but the problem is I need to move the MenuBar component after the Container component in order to put menubar to bottom. Are there any better solutions?

This is the sceenshot of my menu bar
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwWmc.png

Comment: can you provide css or better yet, a jsfiddle?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I have added the css and js code, can you please help me